# BigO(n) or theta(n) auxiliary space in recursion

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I was writing this recursive function to calculate the sum of the first n numbers. I know there is a direct formula for it, but I am doing it for the practice of recursion.

```
int sum(int n)
{
   if (n==0)
     return 0;
   
   return n + sum(n-1);
}
```

I am confused is Auxiliary space required for this function, will it be `O(n)` or `theta(n)`?

Comment: I am confused by your question. -"will it be O(n) for theta(n)?"

Comment: Theta denotes exact bounds, therefore it also implies `O(n)` upper bound.

Comment: The auxiliary space (stack space) will be `O(n)` as well as `Θ(n)`, and the code as written will thwart recursion tail-call optimization.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I noticed the typo, actually I meant will it be O(n) or theta(n). I am Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @Eljay how can both be auxiliary space? I am a bit confused.

Comment: *how can both be auxiliary space?*  I don't understand what you mean and/or are confused about.

Answer (score 2):

Without compiler optimization, the space complexity can be expressed as either O(n) or Θ(n). The former means that the space growth speed will not exceed c*n, where c is a constant, the latter means that the space growth speed is somewhere between c1*n and c2*n, where c1 and c2 are constants. You can see the more formalized definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

With comiler optimization, the situation differs.

```
sum(int):
    xor     eax, eax
    test    edi, edi
    je      .L1
.L2:
    add     eax, edi
    sub     edi, 1
    jne     .L2
.L1:
    ret
```

This is the x64 assembly code generated by GCC 12.1 under optimization level -O2, you can see that there is no recursion, therefore the space complexity will be O(1).